# centering p element inside flex container inside grid container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to center a p element inside a flex-container that is inside a grid-container's 2nd row.

I've tried turning the p element inline though with no success.
The ul element inside the flex-container centers but the p one doesn't so that's really weird.

here's the code:

```css
.accordion {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.accordion-item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;

  gap: 2rem;

  padding: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.hidden-box {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <section class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-item">
        <span>01</span>
        <h2>Where are these chairs assembled?</h2>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          class="arrow-icon"
          fill="none"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          stroke="currentColor"
          stroke-width="2"
        >
          <path
            stroke-linecap="round"
            stroke-linejoin="round"
            d="M15 13l-3 3m0 0l-3-3m3 3V8m0 13a9 9 0 110-18 9 9 0 010 18z"
          />
        </svg>
        <div class="hidden-box">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur badipisicing elit. Dolorem
            nulla voluptatibus vel temporibus voluptates illo quaerat?
            Repudiandae eum exercitationem quisquam!
          </p>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- <div class="accordion-item"></div>
      <div class="accordion-item"></div> -->
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you want the text in the p to be centered?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, but not with text-align.

Comment: The p element is centred inside its container but occupies full width. The text inside the p element can be centred using `text-align: center`. useful information here: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: Why not with text align? Your p element is already centered, it’s the text that is aligned left at the moment.

Comment: @DavePritlove Thank you, however that is not quite what I am trying to do. Do you know how to set the p element the size of it's text? 'display;inline' isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By centering a **p element** if you mean this -

[image: centered p element]

then add **text-align property** to achieve the same -

```
.hidden-box {
   text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, however I mean centering the whole p element inside not the text itself. Meaning the text should not have 'text-align' however, still be centered.

Comment: @noharm the p element is centred. You cannot see that because it is centred but 100% wide (default). Add a style rule for p `width: 70%` and you will see it is centred.

Comment: @DavePritlove Thanks! That exactly what I was looking for!! Is there a way to know how much '%' I need precisely in order for the p element to be the same size as the 'h2' one, or I need to set it by hand to 'h2's' px size?

Comment: A trial-and-error estimate of the h1 pixel width is probably the simplest solution to setting the p width.  It could be computed exactly and set using javascript but it's hardly worth the trouble.

Comment: @DavePritlove tyvm dave